# Is there a way to programmatically set the range of an XYScrollBar in Amcharts 4?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I've got multiple graphs on one page and all are using the same values for the x-axis. When the user selects a range using the scroll bar, I want all graphs to sync to that range. The graph they make the range selection on naturally scrolls, but the other graphs remain staionary.

Is there a way to set the range of a scroll bar from code? I looked at the XYScrollbar reference but didn't find anything in the methods section like setRange(...).

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting **start** and **end** properties of the scrollbar:

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/scrollbar/#start_property
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/scrollbar/#end_property

Updated:

this actually works only once. In order for this to work consistently, I had to use undocumented fixRange(range: IRange) method. I'm not sure I understand why it's not documented.

Answer (score 0):

You can user below property

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/amantandon1/09d3f8cr/1/][1]
```

categoryAxis.end = 0.8;

categoryAxis.start = 0.8;

you can check here
[jsfiddle chart](https://jsfiddle.net/amantandon1/09d3f8cr/1/)[2](https://%20https://jsfiddle.net/amantandon1/09d3f8cr/1/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/amantandon1/09d3f8cr/1/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).